# Is it possible in LibreOffice Writer to "clear" the next paragraph after a frame?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In HTML, you can "clear" a floated DIV so that a paragraph (delineated by a P tag) will be pushed to below the DIV. I want to achieve the same behaviour in LibreOffice writer, so that it will look like this:

[image: Cleared frame]

But, in LibreOffice Writer, I can't find any way of acheiving the same effect. Text always flows around frames, like this:

[image: non cleared frame]

Basically, I want a frame to be aligned with the top of one paragraph, and if it is longer than that paragraph, it pushes the following paragraph down. Is it possible to get the behaviour as shown in the top image in LibreOffice Writer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - with current versions of LibreOffice Writer (*tested with 5.1.2.2 and 5.0.3.2*), you can achieve this by selecting the **wrap option "`First Paragraph`"**. This option is available in the frame's context menu (if the frame is selected). Here's an example of a frame with "`Wrap before`" Wrapping and "`First paragraph`" *not selected* (notice the last entry in the context menu):

[image]

After enabling "`First Paragraph`", the example looks as follows (again, notice the last entry in the context menu, now checked):

[image]

<sup>*Please double-ckeck if you're using the same (current) version of LO - the option may be absent in previous versions (version < 5.x).*</sup>